# Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' , 'dataSource' and 'delegatingApplicationListener'

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I need some help.
I have a Spring project and I'm migrating to a Spring Boot project. but I'm having some issue.
could you help me?

this is the problem

```
2017-05-30 07:39:32.067  INFO 60280 --- [           main]     f.a.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject'     annotation found and supported for autowiring
2017-05-30 07:39:32.332  INFO 60280 --- [           main]     trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'appConfig' of type     [com.santander.portalcio.config.AppConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c8cc79c0] is     not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not     eligible for auto-proxying)
2017-05-30 07:39:32.343  INFO 60280 --- [           main]     trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean     'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfigurat    ion' of type     [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfigurat    ion$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4fca10c8] is not eligible for getting processed     by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2017-05-30 07:39:32.412  WARN 60280 --- [           main]     s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context     initialization - cancelling refresh attempt:     org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating     bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource     [com/santander/portalcio/config/AppConfig.class]: Unsatisfied dependency     expressed through method 'entityManagerFactory' parameter 0; nested exception is     org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean     with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource     [com/santander/portalcio/config/AppConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory     method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.lookup.DataSourceLookupFailureException: Failed to look up JNDI DataSource with name 'jdbc/PortalCIO'; nested exception is javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
2017-05-30 07:39:32.420  WARN 60280 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Error handling failed (Error creating bean with name 'delegatingApplicationListener' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importRegistry' available)
2017-05-30 07:39:32.431 ERROR 60280 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [com/santander/portalcio/config/AppConfig.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'entityManagerFactory' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [com/santander/portalcio/config/AppConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.lookup.DataSourceLookupFailureException: Failed to look up JNDI DataSource with name 'jdbc/PortalCIO'; nested exception is javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:467) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
```

This is my Application class

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
    return configureApplication(builder);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    configureApplication(new SpringApplicationBuilder()).run(args);
}

private static SpringApplicationBuilder configureApplication(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
    return builder.sources(Application.class);
}
```

This is my AppConfig class

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
public class AppConfig {

 @Bean
 public ServletRegistrationBean wsservletRegistration(WSServlet
 wsservletServlet) {
 ServletRegistrationBean registration = new ServletRegistrationBean(
 wsservletServlet);
 registration.addUrlMappings("/indicadoresBSTS*");
 return registration;
 }

@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean filterRegistrationBean() {

    FileUploadFilter fileUploadFilter = new FileUploadFilter();

    CharacterEncodingFilter characterEncodingFilter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();

    FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean();

    registrationBean.setFilter(fileUploadFilter);
    registrationBean.setFilter(characterEncodingFilter);

    return registrationBean;
}

@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    JndiDataSourceLookup dsLookup = new JndiDataSourceLookup();
    dsLookup.setResourceRef(true);
    DataSource ds = dsLookup.getDataSource("jdbc/PortalCIO");
    return ds;
}

@Bean
public AbstractPlatformTransactionManager txManager(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
    return new JpaTransactionManager(emf);
}

@Bean
public PropertiesFactoryBean hibernateProperties() {
    PropertiesFactoryBean bean = new PropertiesFactoryBean();
    bean.setLocations(new ClassPathResource("hibernate.properties"),
            new ClassPathResource("hibernate-test.properties"));
    bean.setIgnoreResourceNotFound(true);
    return bean;
}

@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource,
        Properties hibernateProperties) {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean bean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    bean.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
    bean.setDataSource(dataSource);
    bean.setPersistenceXmlLocation("classpath*:META-INF/spring-persistence.xml");
    bean.setJpaProperties(hibernateProperties);
    return bean;
}

@Bean
public BeanPostProcessor customFunctionRegister() {
    return new CustomFunctionRegisterPostProcessor();
}

public static class CustomFunctionRegisterPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor {

    @Override
    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
        return bean;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
        if (!(bean instanceof EntityManagerFactory)) {
            return bean;
        }

        HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean fac = new HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean();
        fac.setEntityManagerFactory((EntityManagerFactory) bean);
        SessionFactoryImplementor sfi = (SessionFactoryImplementor) fac.getObject();

        SQLFunctionRegistry reg = sfi.getSqlFunctionRegistry();
        Field userFunctionsField;
        Map<String, SQLFunction> userFunctions;
        try {
            userFunctionsField = SQLFunctionRegistry.class.getDeclaredField("userFunctions");
            userFunctionsField.setAccessible(true);

            userFunctions = (Map<String, SQLFunction>) userFunctionsField.get(reg);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new BeanInitializationException("can't read SQLFunctionRegistry.userFunctions", e);
        }

        Dialect dialect = sfi.getDialect();
        userFunctions.put("datediff_minutes", new DateDiffFunction(dialect, TimePart.minute));
        userFunctions.put("datetrunc_day", new DateTruncFunction(dialect, DatePart.day));
        userFunctions.put("datetrunc_month", new DateTruncFunction(dialect, DatePart.month));

        return bean;
    }
}
```

A use the same classes for the old spring project and adapt to start as a Spring boot Project. could anyone have this problems?

for my pom.xml I add spring-boot-starter-parent 1.5.3, spring-boot-starter-web, spring-boot-starter-security, spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb, spring-boot-starter-remote-shell and Spring version 4.3.8

Comment: Where do you define your datasource "jdbc/PortalCIO"?

Comment: spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://127.0.0.1\SQLEXPRESS;databaseName=portal-cio;
spring.datasource.username=portalcio
spring.datasource.password=inmetrics

spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=true

Comment: I think you need to add @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.datasource") annotation  to your dataSource bean

Comment: Please don't add additional information as comments, edit your question instead. You don't have JNDI as you are using an embedded tomcat. Also you are using Spring Boot then use Spring Boot. For starters remove your explicit `DataSource` and enable the auto configuration for it again and Spring Boot will create your `DataSource` for you.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and I solved it by adding `@ComponentScan({ "com.beni_regev" })` to the class where my DataSource is defined and changing the `dataSource` bean to the following (I'm using *Postgres*):

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
   DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
   dataSource.setDriverClassName("thread");
   dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/my_db?loglevel=0");
   dataSource.setUsername(""postgres);
   dataSource.setPassword("admin");
   dataSource.setSchema("public");
   return dataSource;
}
```